# Trying to install Pithos but

Tags: software-installation

by following the instructions here... but when I do I get following errors. Anyone have any ideas as to why? This is a really neat program that I like a lot and would like to get it going again.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pj-assis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/karmic/Release.gpg  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.90.217). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pj-assis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pj-assis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dockbar-main/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dockbar-main/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dockbar-main/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kevin-mehall/pithos-daily/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kevin-mehall/pithos-daily/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kevin-mehall/pithos-daily/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you are trying to download from is having technical problems. If you try again later you shouldn't run into this.

From the [Launchpad status page](http://identi.ca/launchpadstatus/):

> Launchpad.net status
>   (launchpadstatus)'s status on
>   Wednesday, 16-Feb-11 23:56:37 UTC
>
> We've had to restart all our front end
>   HTTP and HTTPS services, there would
>   have been a 10 seconds or so down.
>   Sorry, but was needed.